# Save data to the db in codeigniter 4 using save method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter 4 so i have this controller for saving data from a form in the view but its not saving i dont know what might might be a problem. Can someone please help me?

This is the controller

```
public function save_categories()
{
    $categories = json_encode($this->request->getPost("categories"));

    if ($this->_expenseModel->save(['expense_categories' => $categories]))
    {
        return $this->response->setJSON(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Expense categories updated'));

    }else{

        return $this->response->setJSON(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed! Error while Saving category'));
    }
}
```

And this is the view form :
 'expense_category_form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')); ?>

```
            <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 60vh; overflow-y: scroll;" id="cat_container">

                <table class="text-center" width="100%" border="0">

                    <?php foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>

                        <tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin: 1em .2em" name="categories[]" value="<?=ucwords($cat) ?>"></td><td width="50px"> <span style="cursor: pointer;color: red" title="Delete Category" class="fa remove fa-remove"></span></td></tr>
                        
                    <?php } ?>

                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                
                <span class="btn btn-info" id="btn_new_cat">New Category</span>
                
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_categories" class="btn btn-primary ">Save Changes</a>

            </div>

        <?= form_close(); ?>
```

I tried to remove the automatic save method function being called the model and use insert and update instead but still it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Is this a batch update? Either way, the data should be an array in $categories.

What happens if you change:

```
if ($this->_expenseModel->save(['expense_categories' => $categories]))
```

to:

```
if ($this->_expenseModel->save($categories))
```

Below is an example function I am using to add categories via Ajax from a modal window. This is single and not a batch.
You should be able to get the idea from here:

```
public function add() {

    checkAjax();

    $response = array();

    $fields['expense_categories'] = $this->request->getPost('categories');

    $this->validation->setRules([
        'expense_categories'   => ['label' => 'Category Name', 'rules'   => 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[100]'],
    ]);

    if ($this->validation->run($fields) == FALSE) {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['messages'] = $this->validation->getErrors(); //Show Error in Input Form
    } else {

        if ($this->categoriesModel->insert($fields)) {

            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['messages'] = lang("App.insert-success");
        } else {

            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['messages'] = lang("App.insert-error");
        }
    }

    return $this->response->setJSON($response);
}
```

If you need batch:

```
public function addBatch() {

    checkAjax();
    $temp1 = $this->request->getPost('categories');

    foreach ($temp1 AS $key => $category):
        $fields[] = [
            'expense_categories'       => ($category['categories'])
        ];
    endforeach;

    if ($this->categoriesModel->insertBatch($fields)) {
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['messages'] = lang("App.insert-success");
    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['messages'] = lang("App.insert-error");
    }
    return $this->response->setJSON($response);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It still did not work

Comment: // prepare the data array 
        $data = [
            'expense_categories' =>$this->request->getPost("categories")
        ];

        $this->_expenseModel->save($data);  This is how i changes the code but it still didnt work

Comment: The code commented isn't an update, "save" wont work, you need "insert" - also, your trying to save a nested array which you have'nt yet converted to an Array() and will work best with batch.  Your `save_categories() Function` should look more like my 2nd example above, it will work, I tested it again to be sure. InsertBatch will UPDATE IF an existing ID is found, so make sure you "post" ID's along with the names IF this is an update to existing and an insert of new. Also, post more about the error you get. Check the `/writable/logs/` folder for error messages as well